# How can I get CruiseControl.NET to attach error log in email?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

This is a sample of my publisher setting:

```
<publishers>
  <statistics />
  <xmllogger logDir="F:\ccnet\Project\xxxxxx\Artifacts\buildlogs" />
  <buildpublisher>
    <sourceDir>$(buildDir)\_PublishedWebsites\$(projectName)</sourceDir>
    <publishDir>$(webDir)</publishDir>
    <useLabelSubDirectory>false</useLabelSubDirectory>
    <alwaysPublish>false</alwaysPublish>
  </buildpublisher>
  <email mailport="25"
       mailhostUsername="xxx@xx.xx"
       mailhostPassword="xxxxxxxxx"
       includeDetails="TRUE"
       useSSL="FALSE">
    <includeDetails>TRUE</includeDetails>
    <from>xxxx@xx.xx</from>
    <mailhost>xxxx.xxxx.xxx</mailhost>
    <users>
      <user name="Flemming" group="buildmaster" address="xx@xx.xxu" />
    </users>
    <groups>
      <group name="buildmaster">
        <notifications>
          <notificationType>Always</notificationType>
        </notifications>
      </group>
    </groups>
  </email>
</publishers>
```

In webdashboard everything is fine. it shows all information from the standard xslt list.

After each build I get an email, but it only shows me information from header.xsl, unittest.xsl (shows no unit tests) and modification.xsl. But it doesn't show anything from compile.xsl.

xslfiles from ccnet.exe.config:

```
<xslFiles>
  <file name="xsl\header.xsl"/>
  <file name="xsl\compile.xsl"/>
  <file name="xsl\msbuild.xsl"/>
  <file name="xsl\modifications.xsl"/>
  <!-- <file name="xsl\unittests.xsl"/>
  <file name="xsl\fit.xsl"/>
  <file name="xsl\fxcop-summary_1_36.xsl"/> -->
</xslFiles>
```

What am I missing here?
I tried to insert TRUE as well as having it as an attribute, but no difference.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
Instead of using compile.xsl in the xsllists I now use compile_msbuild.xsl

Now I get all errors and warnings in the mails !!!

Answer (score 0):

From [CCNET's EmailPublisher documentation](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Email_Publisher):

> Make sure that all of the Merge Publishers, along with the Xml Log Publisher task are done before the  publisher, or else you won't be able to include output from the build in the email.

Comment: A valid point, but I don't have any merge publishers, all publishers are listed in the code example